# how to find the xpath for given html code

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

This is the HTML code

```
<td align="right" style="width: 50%">
<span style="padding-right: 10px">
<span id="ctl00_lblLoginUserName" style="font-style:italic;">You are logged in as OSAMIEE    </span>
</span>
<a id="ctl00_LinkButton1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$LinkButton1','')">Log Out</a>
```

when I use this `xpath` for this line,I got the error below:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath == //*[@id='ctl00_lblLoginUserName'] (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 431 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.33.0', revision: '4e90c97', time: '2013-05-22 15:33:32'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_40'
Session ID: 8f0644de-fe65-4d34-a960-ea80a6202f2f
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, elementScrollBehavior=0, javascriptEnabled=true, enablePersistentHover=true, ignoreZoomSetting=false, browserName=internet explorer, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss, version=8, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=true, requireWindowFocus=false, handlesAlerts=true, initialBrowserUrl=, nativeEvents=true, browserAttachTimeout=0, takesScreenshot=true}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:191)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:307)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:404)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:344)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:299)
    at login.Verification.main(Verification.java:173)`
```

Help me to finout this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
//*[@id='ctl00_LinkButton1']
```

also, if the page the link is on is not fully loaded before your code attempts to click it, its likely that the element is not yet visible(which could also result in an exception. In that case use WebDriverWait to wait until the element is loaded.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TIMEOUT); // where TIMEOUT is for example 500 or 1000
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_LinkButton1']")));
element.click();
```

EDIT:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 1000);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_lblLoginUserName']")));
System.out.println(element.getText());
```

prints: You are logged in as OSAMIEE

and

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 1000);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_LinkButton1']")));
System.out.println(element.getText());
```

prints: Log Out

Comment: I need the xpath for the above line not the link button. Its link text I need to get the value of the link text. Thanks for ur reply